# POST Request works with Postman but fails in fetch?

Tags: javascript, networking, postman, react-native

I created backend where it will accept requests to the following url

> http://10.1.0.1/cgi-bin/api/write_config

With Postman I get the appropriate response but when I try the same thing with fetch, I get a network error

This is my code:

```
fetch ('http://10.1.0.1/cgi-bin/api/write_config', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          param1: 'attr1',
          param2: 'attr2',
          param3: 'attr3',
        }),
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.json())
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {

        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('In catch block')
        console.log(e)
      })
```

These are the header I'm getting from the response (in Postman):

Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

I'm getting the following error (in Javascript):

> { [TypeError: Network request failed]   line: 24117,   column: 31,
>   sourceURL:
>   'http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false'
>   }

Edit:

I configured the Raspberry Pi in the same way in which I configured the other device then the output is correct. Is it some certificate issue with Javascript?

Comment: This could be like the "works with curl but fails in Firefox". The answer there is: curl doesn't care about the CORS headers. Sometimes even Chrome works but Firefox fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android Emulator try to use your IP Address instead of 10.1.0.1 - I had network request errors too but it worked with my IP.

Comment: I am not using an emulator. I created a device with Wifi and I need to send data to configure it. So I connect to the device's wifi and send the data

Answer (score 0):

did u tried console.log(body) ? sometimes JSON not work. if u don't have problem with body . I'm sure header is wrong

Comment: I was thinking it was due to CORS that's why I add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in response of the header