# Authentication POST works in 'request' but not with 'node-fetch'

Tags: javascript, npm, cookies, request, node-fetch

I've written an authentication request that works with the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module but fails to return the desired 'authentication token' cookie with the [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) module that I'm trying to move towards since 'request' has been deprecated.

Here is the working code using 'request'

```
  var callback1 = function(err, httpResponse, body){
    console.log("Correctly prints all the cookies we want: ");
    console.log(httpResponse.headers["set-cookie"]);
    if (err){console.log("here it is!"); throw err;}
    else {
      //do more with response
    }
  };
 var callback0 = function(err, httpResponse0, body){

    console.log("Check that sent cookies are identical, from request:");
    console.log(httpResponse0.headers["set-cookie"][0].substr(0,httpResponse0.headers["set-cookie"][0].indexOf(";")));
    if (err){throw err;}
    else {
    var options1 = {
      url: urlString1
      ,headers:{
      'Host': hostName
      ,'User-Agent': myUserAgent
      ,'Accept': myAccept 
      ,'Accept-Language':myAcceptLanguage 
      ,'Accept-Encoding': myAcceptEncoding 
      ,'Referer': "https://"+hostName+'/login'
      ,'Cookie': httpResponse0.headers["set-cookie"][0].substr(0,httpResponse0.headers["set-cookie"][0].indexOf(";"))
      ,'Content-Type':  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ,'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(querystring.stringify(postData))
      ,'Connection': "keep-alive"
      ,'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1"
      ,'DNT': "1"
      ,'TE': "Trailers"
      }
      ,form: {email: myEmail, password: myPassword}
    };
    request.post(options1, callback1);
    }
  }
 var options0 = {
    url: urlString0
    ,headers:{
    'Host': hostName
    ,'User-Agent': myUserAgent
    ,'Accept': myAccept 
    ,'Accept-Language':myAcceptLanguage 
    ,'Accept-Encoding': myAcceptEncoding 
    ,'Referer': "https://"+hostName
    ,'Connection': "keep-alive"
    ,'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1"
    }
  };
  request(options0, callback0);
```

And here is the code in node-fetch that's failing to properly return the auth_token cookie:

```
  const fetchOptions0 = {
      method: 'GET', 
      headers:{
      'Host': hostName
      ,'User-Agent': myUserAgent
      ,'Accept': myAccept 
      ,'Accept-Language':myAcceptLanguage 
      ,'Accept-Encoding': myAcceptEncoding 
      ,'Referer': "https://"+hostName
      ,'Connection': "keep-alive"
      ,'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1"
      }
  }
  fetch(urlString0, fetchOptions0)
  .then(res0 => {
    console.log("Check that sent cookies are identical, from fetch:");
    console.log(res0.headers.raw()['set-cookie'][0].substr(0, res0.headers.raw()['set-cookie'][0].indexOf(";")));
    const FormData = require('form-data');
    const myForm = new FormData();
    myForm.append('email', myEmail);
    myForm.append('password', myPassword);
    var fetchOptions1 = {
      method: 'POST'
      ,headers:{
      'Host': hostName
      ,'User-Agent': myUserAgent
      ,'Accept': myAccept 
      ,'Accept-Language':myAcceptLanguage 
      ,'Accept-Encoding': myAcceptEncoding 
      ,'Referer': "https://"+hostName+'/login'
      ,'Cookie': res0.headers.raw()['set-cookie'][0].substr(0, res0.headers.raw()['set-cookie'][0].indexOf(";"))
      ,'Content-Type':  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ,'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(querystring.stringify(postData))
      ,'Connection': "keep-alive"
      ,'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1"
      ,'DNT': "1"
      ,'TE': "Trailers"
    }
    ,body:myForm
    };
    fetch(urlString1, fetchOptions1)
    .then(res1=> {console.log("Incorrect cookie, missing auth:"); console.log(res1.headers.raw()['set-cookie']);});
    });
```

I have tried writing the form data using JSON.stringify as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952291/post-request-works-with-postman-but-fails-in-fetch) answer, but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you show the console.logs of both the request and node-request implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There is

> ,form: {email: myEmail, password: myPassword}

in `request` version of code. It is **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**
See https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-url-encoded-forms)

But there is

> body: myForm

in `fetch` version of code. And it is **`multipart/form-data`**
See

1. first sentence of https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#post-with-form-data-detect-multipart

But still

> 'Content-Type':  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

in the `fetch` version

If your API endpoint doesn't accept `multipart/form-data` you probably should switch from `FormData` to `URLSearchParams`.
See https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#post-with-form-parameters

Comment: I've tried using UrlSearchParams, too, but unfortunately the cookie still doesn't come through.

Comment: Then, please, add request and response headers from both versions of your code

Comment: and by the way - what is `postData`. I do not see it's being posted.

Comment: Maybe `fetchOptions1.body` size does not match `Content-Length`. And why would you set it manually, anyway?

Comment: I had set it manually because I was trying to send the exact same request, line for line, that I saw in Dev Tools, and I wasn't sure it would automatically set otherwise. I have tried removing that and it still doesn't return the right cookie.

Comment: 1) remove headers from `request` version one by one while `request` still works 2) remove same headers from `fetch` version 3) use `UrlSearchParams` with `fetch` instead of `FormData`. If you'd do all these steps it should work... if not then in DevTools you should be able to right-click on a request done by `request` version and select `Copy/Copy as fetch`, maybe that would do the trick. Any way, update you question with requests and responses.

Comment: You also can try `body: querystring.stringify(postData)`. I still have no clue what the `postData` is. But the code in the question is definitely not the full story, so this advice can still work for you

Comment: Strangely it still doesn't work. I was able to get the main "request" down to no headers at all! It seems like the problem is with the submission of the "form." Sorry I didn't post postData, it's just the object {email: myEmail, password: myPassword}

Answer (score 0):

To send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload into the body, simply pass a URLSearchParams object

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("email", myEmail);
params.append("password", myPassword);

fetch(urlString1, {
  headers: {
    // your headers
    // omit content-length and content-type because node-fetch
    // will handle that for you
  },
  body: params
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response.headers.raw());
})
```

In your example, you seem to be using FormData, which results in node-fetch writing `multipart/formdata` as the header's `content-type`.

Also you might want to check your authorization server code to see if it sends the `set-cookie` headers correctly.

Tested with:

- node-fetch v2.6.0
- nodejs v12.14.0

Comment: As noted below, this doesn't work :( is it any hint that URLSearchParams() isn't blue when I type it?

Comment: You might be using old nodejs where URLSearchParams must be required first using
`const { URLSearchParams } = require("url");`